# Padrão de Projeto Observer no Android

Tags: java, android, orientação-a-objetos

Alguém teria como me mostrar uma estrutura Observer dentro do android?

Estava tentando montar uma igual a do java, porém não tive sucesso.

Meu teste foi feito da seguinte forma:

- Criei uma `class Banco` e uma `class ClienteObservable`;
- No banco eu tenho os métodos de notificação, e de `adicionarObserver` (que eu passo a bola pro `clienteObservable`);
- Na `class ClienteObservable` eu tenho o método `update`, que vai realizar um ação ao ser notificado.

Essa é a lógica que tenho sobre Padrão de Projeto Observer, porém não sei como estruturar isso no [android](/questions/tagged/android), alguém poderia desenvolver algo bem básico para me mostrar?

Segue abaixo o Código:

Na Class Banco
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na Class clienteObservable
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia postar o código que você implementou em java? Aproveitando pode deixar as classes com o padrão do Java com a primeira letra maiúscula.

Comment: Adicionei a imagem, e vi que o metodo notify esta sem nenhuma ação com o observador, eu imaginei que poderia ser uma outra forca me usar o observer

Comment: Qual o erro que esta tendo no android?

Comment: Nenhum erro, apenas não executada nada, coloquei pra toda vez que o observador receber uma notificação, ele exibir um Toast, e isso nao é executado, como e flei, meu metodo notify Observeer não esta executando nada(eu acho), vou testar quando chegar do serviço.

Comment: Você precisa chamar explicitamente notifyObservers toda vez que alterar seu objeto. da mesma forma que coloquei na minha classe na resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja igual o java.

```
public class Cliente {
}
public interface ClienteObservable {
    public void update();
}
public class Banco {
    private List<ClienteObservable> observables = new ArrayList<ClienteObservable>();
    public void adicionarObserver(ClienteObservable obs){
       this.observables.add(obs);
    }
}
```

Mas existe um erro conceitual aqui. Na verdade deveria ser assim:

```
public interface ClienteObserver {
    public void update(Cliente cliente);
}
public class Banco implements ClienteObserver {
    @Override
    public void update(Cliente cliente) {
        //faz algum calculo para o cliente  ..
    }
}
public class Cliente {
    private String nome;
    private List<ClienteObserver> observers = new ArrayList<ClienteObserver>();

    public void adicionarObserver(ClienteObserver obs) {
        this.observers.add(obs);
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.notifyObservers();
    }
    private void notifyObservers() {
        for (ClienteObserver observer : this.observers) {
            observer.update(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Pois quem você esta observando é o objeto Cliente. 
Quando ele atualizar seu estado deve comunicar os observadores sobre esta modificação.

Comment: Testei oque você me mandou, realmente isso funciona no java , porem no android não, eu ainda acredito que no android tem que ser uma estrutura diferente.

Comment: Como este exemplo é isolado ele deve funcionar igual ao desktop.
Pode dar mais detalhes do seu problema?