# Como funciona e como implementar o Design Pattern Observer?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, observer-pattern

Estou na dúvida em relação Design Pattern Observer, quando ao seu funcionamento e como utilizar(apresentar exemplo prático).

Comment: Vê a resposta do @Mubarak (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744450/interview-when-do-we-use-observer-and-observable) e as outras também!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Introdução

Quando você gosta muito de uma revista você pode ir na banca todos os dias para ver se chegou a nova edição ou pode fazer uma assinatura e receber em casa. O padrão observador é exatamente a assinatura de algo que você quer receber quando algo acontecer. Ou seja, sempre que uma classe precisa saber que uma ação ocorreu ou um estado foi alterado em outra classe (em tese poderia ser na mesma classe, mas dentro dela mesma existem mecanismos mais simples de usar).

Você ter que ficar verificando se algo aconteceu com constância não dá certo. Vai consumir muito processamento e possivelmente você vai acabar deixando passar o momento exato que um evento ocorreu. É impraticável, o programa precisa saber exatamente quando algo importante ocorreu e ser notificado disto imediatamente.

Há algumas maneiras de fazer a implementação disto embora os puristas vão dizer que se fizer diferente do que foi estabelecido oficialmente pelo padrão ele não é exatamente o padrão Observer. Eu não vou me prender à implementação pura.

## Funcionamento

Basicamente você tem dois agentes, a classe observável (conhecida como Subject) e a observadora.

Na classe observável você precisa ter um estado: a lista que guarda os assinantes; e três comportamentos: quem faz a adição de um novo assinante na lista, quem faz a retirada de um assinante, e quem notifica a lista de assinantes que algum evento relevante para eles ocorreu.

Na classe observadora você precisa de uma ação a ser realizada quando for notificado que algo que lhe interessa ocorreu.

[image: Diagrama padrão Observer]

É uma forma de encapsular comportamento, garantindo que outros objetos saibam de algo que você determina sem precisarem saber de detalhes de implementação desta classe. Se quiser uma definição mais formal, [veja na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), tem até um exemplo em Java.

## Uso

Ele é usado quando você precisa saber que algo aconteceu na sua aplicação através dela própria ou bibliotecas que eventualmente por sua vez ficam observando se serviços externos à aplicação tem algo a notificar.

No primeiro caso pode ser um cálculo que ocorreu, o término de uma operação, um erro de validação ou outro tipo, uma alteração provocada na tela, um estado de um objeto que foi alterado, um objeto que será destruído, etc.

No segundo caso as classes observáveis na superfície trabalham da mesma forma embora a implementação específica pode fugir desta forma já que ele precisa "conversar" com APIs externas de servidores e o sistema operacional que provavelmente não implementam este padrão exatamente desta forma, apenas possuem alguma outra forma de sinalização. Você usa bibliotecas que notificam sua aplicação conforme demanda quando recebe sinais de dispositivos (teclado, mouse, rede, etc.), informações de operações do sistema operacional e seus componentes (modificação de arquivo ou sistema de arquivos, troca ou início/fim de componente de software ou hardware, comunicação de dados, enfim, diversas ações que ocorrem naquela máquina) e operações ocorridas em serviços (modificação de uma tabela no banco de dados, recebimento de requisição em servidor web, etc.).

Padrões que lidam com interfaces com usuário costumam usar bastante o *Observer pattern*, seja [MVC, MVP, MMVP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/101), etc.

## Um exemplo

Pense em um jogo que o inimigo sendo morto precisa atualizar o placar. O placar precisa assinar a notificação de morte do inimigo para mudar seu estado. O inimigo terá métodos para interessados assinarem e cancelarem a assinatura do evento de morte e terá um método que notifica todos estes assinantes. Quando este objeto do inimigo tiver a morte decretada por algum critério deverá disparar este último método.

O objeto placar pode ser um dos assinantes. Ele poderá chamar o método de inscrição na lista de assinantes. Este objeto certamente terá um método que será invocado quando o evento ocorrer.

Note que qualquer parte da aplicação pode fazer a assinatura deste evento, inclusive o próprio objeto do inimigo. Isto pode não ser tão comum mas pode fazer sentido. A morte deste inimigo, por exemplo pode disparar a destruição do objeto e garantir que a lista de assinantes seja destruída junto. E pode ser que a destruição do objeto seja outro evento. Pode ser ainda que o cancelamento forçado da inscrição gere um outro evento. Enfim, você pode criar um evento sempre que achar que tem "alguém" querendo saber que você fez algo neste objeto.

Para irritação dos puristas a classe do inimigo poderia fazer a assinatura do placar, porque pode ser que esta classe saiba da existência do placar mas não o contrário. Ou seja, o inimigo sabe que precisa mudar o placar quando ocorrer a sua morte mas o placar não sabe tudo o que pode acontecer que o modifique. Evidentemente o placar precisa ter um método de ação preparado para ser invocado por um evento.

Os puristas ficariam mais confortáveis se você tiver uma classe separada, possivelmente uma mediadora para controlar essas relações entre observáveis e observadores. E você começa ter algo que funciona de forma análoga a um MVC.

## Usando em Java

Você pode fazer sua própria implementação do padrão usando os critérios e o algoritmo que achar melhor.

Você pode escolher que a assinatura da notificação ocorra com base na classe observadora como um todo (chama um método padrão desta classe estabelecido em interface) ou através de métodos específicos. O segundo caso era muito complicado de fazer manualmente em Java até a versão 7 que não possuia *[lambdas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101)*. Esta forma é bem mais flexível e poderosa que a primeira. Eu posso até ignorar alguma coisa mas nunca gostei da primeira forma onde o observador precisa saber o que fazer com notificações genéricas. E uma nota importante: algumas pessoas vão dizer que a segunda forma não é *observer*.

O padrão é tão comum que o Java tem ele já implementado. O mais comum é usar a classe abstrata [Observable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) e a interface [Observer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) existentes no *framework*. O primeiro já tem todos os métodos para cumprir o papel do padrão (não só os mínimos necessários) e possui uma implementação padrão da lista de assinantes para você não se preocupar.

Algumas linguagens vão mais além e colocam facilidades nelas próprias, como é o caso do `event` do C#.

Tem um exemplo para o Android [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10364/101).

## Conclusão

Eu poderia continuar detalhando, dando mais exemplos, mas a internet já está cheia de material. Acho interessante ter aqui algumas informações básicas mas seria um exagero ter uma abordagem completa. De qualquer forma, acho que cabe respostas complementares de detalhes que eu deixei de lado.

- [Boa explicação e exemplo](https://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) (em inglês).
- [Outro exemplo prático](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternObserver/article.html) (em inglês).
- [Um exemplo que pode ser facilmente "observável"](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm) (em inglês).
- [Um exemplo "na mão" feito em C#](https://www.dofactory.com/net/observer-design-pattern) (em inglês).
- [Explicação genérica](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer) (em inglês).
- [**O** livro](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Design_Patterns.html?id=6oHuKQe3TjQC).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Se gostou od *pattern Observer* e percebeu que programação não é para você e está pensando trocar de profissão, tem uma link para você sobre o assunto: http://patternobserver.com/ :D