# Qual a diferença entre event e delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, eventos, delegate

Já entendi como funciona `delegate` e `event`, mas não vi utilidade do `event`.
Por exemplo:

```
public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, BaseEventArgs e);
public ChangedEventHandler Changed;
```

O código acima funciona como o de baixo:

```
public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, BaseEventArgs e);
public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;
```

Se ambos funcionam da mesma forma, qual a utilidade do `event`?

Pelo o que entendi (se eu estiver errado, me corrijam) o `event` é um modificador que mostra que ele está instanciando um `delegate` que tem como parâmetros uma classe derivada do `EventArgs` e um object? E que também `event` pode ser colocado em interfaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O sistema de eventos é um mecanismo muito mais poderoso. Ela usa delegados como base mas ele faz mais do que isto. Ele é a implementação na linguagem do que se chama de [`Observer Pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) ([exemplo de implementação em C#](http://www.dofactory.com/net/observer-design-pattern)).

Note que no exemplo mostrado no *link* acima tudo o que precisa ser feito para ter um evento funcionando precisa ser feito pelo programador. O comando `event` diz ao compilador que ele deve fazer parte deste "trabalho sujo" para você. Não que ele seja muito complicado, mas certamente dá mais trabalho e é mais fácil cometer erros quando tem mais como que se preocupar.

Nada impede que você implemente [este padrão de projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36655/101) por conta própria com delegados ou mesmo sem eles. Mas você vai ter que escrever todo o código necessário para isto. Terá que garantir que ele está tudo certo. Terá que escrever todo o mecanismo que gerencia os mecanismos de inscrição e desligamento do evento, além do processo de notificação.

O evento abstrai o mecanismo. Ele é um conceito em mais alto nível. De uma certa forma podemos dizer que tema a mesma relação do abordado [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101).

Uma forma de ver o que um evento faz é assim:

```
private ChangedEventHandler ChangedField;
public void AddChangedHandler(ChangedEventHandler handler) => this.ChangedField = (ChangedEventHandler)Delegate.Combine(this.Changed, handler);
public void RemoveChangedHandler(ChangedEventHandler handler) => this.ChangedField = (ChangedEventHandler)Delegate.Remove(this.Changed, handler);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Event.cs).

O compilador implementa isto para você. E não é tão simples fazer certo porque ele implementa isto através de um [`MulticastDelegate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.multicastdelegate?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Novamente, nada impede que você faça isto e pode até precisar se precisar fazer algo mais específico. Ele também dá mais segurança impedindo que certas operações sejam feitas com os delegados. Sem o seu uso, é possível levantar um evento externamente, é possível substituir um delegado indevidamente.

No mais seu entendimento está correto. Não espere muita mágica nele. Ele não faz nada que não pode ser feito sem ele de uma forma "pior".

Se você não liga pela facilidade que ele dá, pelo menos deveria usar para deixar semanticamente claro que você está usando um evento e não só um delegado. È também uma questão de intenção. È uma informação útil para o programador entender melhor o código, permite o compilador fazer algo a mais e permite que outros componentes interajam com ele de forma mais específica, já que ele sabe melhor para que esses delegados estão sendo usados e como eles foram implementados.

Experimenta usa das duas formas e pega o código CIL gerado pelo compilador para ver como muda.

Nem todo mundo sabe que o C# nasceu por causa de uma desavença da Microsoft com a Sun - criadora do Java - por causa deste recurso. Pelo menos é o que diz a lenda. Sorte nossa :)

- [Guia de uso do mecanismo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- [Artigo na MSDN Magazine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2001/august/net-implementation-of-events-with-delegates?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- [Coleção de artigo bem interessantes](https://web.archive.org/web/20151121195228/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/tags/events/).
- [Excelente artigo do Jon Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx).
- [Resposta dele no SO dando mais detalhes de como isto é implementado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/213651/221800).
- [Outro artigo que vale a leitura](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1474/Events-and-event-handling-in-C).