# Parar um processamento em java

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho um processamento com uma classe chamando uma outra.

Exemplo:

Tenho a **registro0100**. Nela chamo o **ED022**, **ED021**, etc....

Nesta **ED022**, tenho umas validações, exemplo:

```
boolean achou = false;
if (modulo.equals("2")) {
    String[] linhaSeparada = listaParametros.get(5).split(Pattern.quote("|"));
    if (linhaSeparada[0].equals(tipoCnso)) {
        achou = true;
    }
}
if (!achou) {
    apontandoErroAlerta(arquivo, erroAlerta, tipoRegistroCampo, tipoRegistro, erroAlertaEncontradoRepository,
    erroAlertaCampoEncontradoRepository, tipoCnso, contadorLinha, registro, erroAlertaRepository,
    tipoRegistroCampoRepository, tipoRegistroRepository);
        return;
}
```

Se a variável achou vira **true**, ele aponta o erro e deveria parar o processo. Mas não para.

Não deveria ir para o erro **ED021**, mas vai.

Como fazer para parar o processo mesmo.

Comment: Talvez se você retornar para sua Classe Registro0100 um `boolean`, poderia testar se "achou" ou não lá, e ai evita que o metodo continue executando.

Comment: @PauloH.Hartmann, já tinha imaginado isto, mas não queria assim. Não tem outra possibilidade ?

Lançar uma exceção sem mensagem. não estava querendo fazer este retorno, pois é muita classe ligando a outra.

Até chegar no início.

Comment: Vou tentar colocar um exemplo melhor:

Queria saber como para um processo iniciado, seja em qualquer classe, sem se por retorno.

Tenho as classes registro0100, ED022, ED023 Erro

O processo inicia na classe registro0100.

A classe registro0100, chama a classe ED022

Se a classe ED022, tiver erro chamar a classe Erro e para o processo na classe Erro
Se a classe ED022 não tiver erro chama a classe ED021

Se a classe ED023, tiver erro chamar a classe Erro e para o processo na classe Erro
Se a classe ED023finalizou corretamente

Conseguiu entender ?

Comment: Talvez o padrão de projeto Observer não lhe ajudaria? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36655/como-funciona-e-como-implementar-o-design-pattern-observer