# MVC versus MVVM

Tags: mvc, design-pattern, arquitetura-de-software, mvvm

Não consigo diferenciar entre ambos MVC ou MVVM. O que realmente diferencia o MVC do MVVM? Em entrevistas de emprego, às vezes perguntam exatamente isso, como você diferencia uma da outra.

Comment: Vinculada: [O que é MVP e MVVM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/18246)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é MVP e MVVM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21539/o-que-%c3%a9-mvp-e-mvvm)

Comment: MVP não é o mesmo que MVC

Comment: Acho que juntando com isso dá dup: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55486/101

Comment: No link do bigown não vi nada sobre MVVM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode responder com uma citação do Josh Smith:

> If you put ten software architects into a room and have them discuss what the Model-View-Controller pattern is, you will end up with twelve different opinions

Aí diz que se colocar 10 desenvolvedores para discutir sobre o MVC, haverá 12 definições diferentes. O MVVM não é tão diferente, ainda que ele seja mais novo, menos usado e com uma definição de quem criou mais clara.

Muitos padrões não são bem definidos. Eu já tive várias discussões com várias pessoas muito inteligentes e nunca se chegou a uma conclusão definitiva. Então se o lugar que está se candidatando é bom, dar uma resposta explicando seu ponto de vista é melhor que dar uma resposta "certeira", porque a sua resposta pode estar certa e eles acharem que está errada, ou vice e versa. Vai responder o que? Uma das doze definições que o Josh Smith fala?

E se eles quiserem mesmo saber uma definição? Isso é quase uma loteria. E o lugar provavelmente não é bom pra se trabalhar. E lamento dizer que não tem muito o que fazer se eles não aceitarem uma explicação do problema.

Dependendo do contexto, da tecnologia ou ambiente, a definição pode ser diferente e estar correta.

De qualquer forma uma resposta aqui não ajudará muito porque a pergunta não deve ser se sabe a definição e sim se sabe usar, aí precisa estudar ambos profundamente.

Não vou explicar cada um porque isso já existe, conforme mostram os comentários.

## Diferença

O resumo sobre a diferença entre eles é que o MVVM tem uma facilidade para trabalhar o modelo específico necessário para a visão.

É comum que o modelo necessário pela visão não bata com o modelo de dados da origem (muitas vezes um banco de dados).

A camada ModelView fará a comunicação da visão (*data-binding*) e o modelo produzindo um outro modelo mais adequado e já trabalhado para atender a visão e pegará o que a visão precisa para solicitar de forma mais adequada para o modelo (*command*). Em geral ela é rica de capacidade para manipular essa comunicação de forma transparente. MVVM faz muito uso do [padrão Observable](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36655/101) (*notifications*).

Fora isso depende de contexto e de mais detalhes do que deseja saber, de onde está sendo usado, qual o objetivo.

## Conclusão

Saber argumentar é melhor que saber o que é ou até mesmo saber fazer.

Além dos *links* nos comentários, pode ver o que eles são na Wikipedia ([MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) e [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel)), pode ver em português, mas nunca acho bom.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).