# JavaFX: prós e contras do MVC, MVP, MVVM, etc

Tags: java, mvc, javafx, mvvm

Qual padrão Modelo-Visão (MV) usar com JavaFX pensando-se em escalabilidade e boa manutibilidade?

No Google você acha gente recomendando MVC, [MVP](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/180468/93338), [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44367581/2241463)... talvez haja outros.

Uns dizem que o JavaFX [foi feito para se usar com MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30556388/2241463). Outros admitem que [há muitas variações possíveis mas preferem o MVP ao MVC, embora este pareça mais natural](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32343342/2241463). Uns dizem que o JavaFX é [agnóstico e aceita qualquer um dos padrões](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R2ROECMWZNYVUK/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=1430265744) (e pelo tom da conversa implicam que faltam livros discutindo os padrões). Outros que [vai depender do problema a ser atacado](https://www.quora.com/Mvc-or-MVP-Which-should-I-use-in-ny-javafx-project).

No fundo, talvez o que conte sejam essas duas últimas opiniões. Resta então listar e discutir os prós e contras de se adotar cada padrão. Espero que isso não seja amplo demais, mas pode ser que seja.

Talvez eu devesse aprender mais sobre JavaFX para perguntar coisas mais específicas. Mas queria ter um norte de como estudar e organizar minhas aplicações, e nisso entra a adoção de um padrão.

A propósito, para o caso do Swing eu encontrei [essa recomendação](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2105582/2241463) que tem ares de autoritativa.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214658/101

Comment: O uso de MVC é apontado como uma boa prática pela Oracle (https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/best_practices/jfxpub-best_practices.htm) quando estamos utilizando o FXML pra construção de telas. Mas quando não se usa o FXML (eu particularmente acho horrível) eles não dizem nada a respeito.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, acredito que vai variar de acordo com seu projeto e com o que se sinta mais a vontade.
 Eu estou em um projeto a qual uso MVCD (*Model, View, Controller e DAO*) dessa forma não vejo dificuldades em organizar a estrutura.
 
E trabalhando com o JAVAFX temos também a parte de CSS que faz parte da View então o ideal e você se organizar de uma maneira que não se perca na estrutura.

Abraço.