# Alternativa a Observable e Observer em Java 9

Tags: java, design-pattern, característica-linguagem, observer-pattern, java-9

Para fins de teste, estou portando uma aplicação da versão 7 para a versão 9 do Java.

Esta aplicação possuí algumas funcionalidades que utilizam `Observer` e `Observable`.

Percebi que ambas se tornaram obsoletas:

```
@Deprecated(since="9") public class Observable extends Object    
@Deprecated(since="9") public interface Observer
```

- Porque foram marcadas como tal?
- Existe uma alternativa para essa funcionalidade?
- Como fica o [Design Pattern Observer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36655/como-funciona-e-como-implementar-o-design-pattern-observer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como toda função que se torna obsoleta, elas não atendiam bem as necessidades, foram mal projetadas e agora tem soluções melhores.

Esses tipos eram gerais demais, não carregavam informações importantes sobre o evento e não eram tão seguras do ponto de vista da tipagem.

O pessoal reclamava que não era capaz de lidar com concorrência e serializar o objeto.

Posição oficial:

> They don't provide a rich enough event model for applications. For example, they support only the notion that something has changed, but they don't convey any information about what has changed. There are also some thread-safety and sequencing issues that cannot be fixed compatibly.

[Fonte](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154801).

[Todo o padrão foi mal pensado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11632412/221800). Por isso que deve se tomar cuidado com *design patterns*.

Uma das alternativas é o [`PropertyChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) que geralmente é mais específico, mais simples e é o que deseja.

Se precisar de algo mais poderoso pode usar a classe [`Flow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Flow.html). A própria [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Observable.html) indica isso.

Answer (score 2):

A criação do Observer é creditada, segundo Martin Fowler, à implementação do MVC no SmallTalk (veja [GUI Architectures](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html)). A ideia central do padrão é notificar observadores quando algum observável encontra-se em um estado de interesse dos observadores. No caso do MVC, os modelos eram observáveis e as visões observadoras. Quando o modelo mudava, a visão era notificada e alterava aquilo que era exibido para o usuário.

Nenhum (nenhum talvez seja muito forte) padrão de projeto é, em essência, ruim. Existem cenários em que seu uso pode ser interessante e outros em que não. É sempre importante avaliar os prós e contras, bem como alternativas, quando se escolhe entre um padrão ou outro.

No caso do Java, conforme o Maniero mencionou, a Oracle menciona como motivação para tornar os componentes obsoletos principalmente o fato de não existir uma ordem garantida para a notificação dos observadores (o que pode ser um problema).

Mas o fato da Oracle ter tornado os componentes obsoletos não significa que você deva parar de usar o padrão. A implementação de Observable e Observer no Java é bem simples. Não é difícil criar uma versão sua que corrija os problemas mencionados pela Oracle.

No link mencionado pelo Maniero com motivos para não usar o Observer, existem várias críticas que se aplicam muito mais ao exemplo que o autor do post escolheu dar do que propriamente às características do padrão, para citar apenas alguns:

**Side-effects** Observadores não precisam ser stateless. Não creio que haja menção a isso no livro do GoF, mas, mesmo que haja, é uma sugestão de como usar, não uma regra.

**Encapsulation** Para o exemplo que o autor deu, sim, mas no próprio exemplo mecionado da visão (MVC), não há quebra de encapsulamento.

**Composability** A necessidade de descartar diversos observadores ao mesmo tempo é muito mais uma demanda específica de domínio do que uma regra geral que possa desmerecer o padrão.

**Separation of concerns** Aqui o autor do post sugere usar o MVC, talvez não sabendo que sua implementação original previa justamente o Observer...

Quanto ao [PropertyChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html), um ponto a observar é que ele trata mudanças em propriedades individualmente e não em conjunto, como uma implementação mais genérica do Observer permitiria fazer. Se este for o seu contexto, atende bem.